# Galeria simples não quer rodar

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando usar um código javascript só que eu não sei nada sobre.

Aprendi o básico vendo video aula online, ainda não sei criar um código, peguei esse aqui no site, só que esse código não quer roda.

(Eu não sei se devo cria um arquivo .js ou colocar esse código com script type=text/javascript).

Obs: Tentei dos dois modos e não funcionou, se alguém tiver outro código ou arrumar uma solação agradeço.

"Eu quero fazer os slides do site da Nintendo, agora estou tentando fazer o número que fica rodando na galeria da nintendo ".

java.js:

```
function iniciarSlideImagens() {


var exibirImagens = function(current) {
    var arrImgsAmarelas = [ 'contador0.png', 'contador1.png' ];
    var arrImgsLaranjas = [ 'contador2.png', 'contador3.png' ];

    document.getElementById("imagem").src = "cores-roleta/" + arrImgsAmarelas[current];
    document.getElementById("imagem1").src = "cores-roleta/" + arrImgsLaranjas[current];

    if (++current >= arrImgsAmarelas.length) {
        current = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(function() { exibirImagens(current); }, 1000);
};

exibirImagens(0);


}
if(2>1){
iniciarSlideImagens();

}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="imagem" src="cores-roleta/contador0.png">
<img id="imagem1" src="cores-roleta/contador2.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código funcionando, o que tinha que fazer era iniciar a chamada "iniciarSlideImagens", que seria `onclick="iniciarSlideImagens()"` na div ou colocar na função, `window.onload = function(){` que seria iniciar o script ao acessar o site.

Código completo com html e jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Site</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){


            var exibirImagens = function(current) {
                var arrImgsAmarelas = [ 'contador0.png', 'contador1.png' ];
                var arrImgsLaranjas = [ 'contador2.png', 'contador3.png' ];

                document.getElementById("imagem").src = "cores-roleta/" + arrImgsAmarelas[current];
                document.getElementById("imagem1").src = "cores-roleta/" + arrImgsLaranjas[current];

                if (++current >= arrImgsAmarelas.length) {
                    current = 0;
                }

                setTimeout(function() { exibirImagens(current); }, 1000);
            };

            exibirImagens(0);


        }
        if(2>1){
            iniciarSlideImagens();

        }
    </script>
    <img id="imagem" src="cores-roleta/contador0.png">
    <img id="imagem1" src="cores-roleta/contador2.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Não é necessário colocar esse código com script `type=text/javascript` o HTML5 já reconhece que é um código em javascript.

Comment: Obrigado,código perfeito e funcionando .

Comment: De nada, qualquer coisa só falar.